# About getopts function

Tags: bash

I'm back again :(
Still some problem with bash, the question is about to make the script to read an option -r then do some further further operation. I think I make it right but when I tried to run it, I got a feedback saying:" ./stripchars: line 20: -r: No such file or directory". And another one saying:" ./stripchars: line 26: ne: command not found"
Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
while getopts "r:" o; do
case "${o}" in
    r)
        r=${OPTARG}
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
if [ ! -z "$FILE" ]
then
exec 0< "$FILE"
fi
while IFS='' read -r LINE
do
echo "$LINE" | tr -d '${r}'
done
if [ -z "${r}" ]
then
if [ ! -z "$FILE" ]
then
    exec 0< "$FILE"
fi
while IFS='' read -r LINE
    do
    echo "$LINE" | tr -d '[:punct:]'
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file name really is the first argument (as implied by `FILE=$1`), then `getopts` has a non-zero exit status *immediately* (since the first argument is not an option), and you never enter the loop. You need to change your call to something like

```
myscript -r whatever foo.txt
```

and move `FILE=$1` *after* the loop that parses the options.